# How to store null into MySQL date column

Tags: mysql, laravel

I try to insert `null` into a `date` field in the MySQL database. But in the db, the old value remains always.

```
    $table->date('due_date')->nullable()->default(null);
```

Method:

```
    public function update(Request $request, Issue $issue)
    {
        $issue->due_date = null;

        $issue->save();

        return response()->json(new IssueResource($issue->fresh()));
    }
```

I searched for the solution, but no success. Neither the same question in SO helped.

Comment: Did you look for errors in the logs to see if you can get an idea why

Comment: Can you inspect your DB to make sure it agrees the migration?

Comment: $table->date('due_date')->nullable(); You are not want use ->default(null); without that ->nullable() is default set null; Show in https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes

Comment: @RiggsFolly no error in the log

Comment: @BrianThompson yes

Comment: @MDReal i changed it but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you read the [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) documentation, as your problem is probably that it is not in the property's `$fillable` `due_date` field as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

If you are sure that the `due_date` field is in that `$fillable` property, then manually check the database and make sure you can change that column to nullable

Comment: `due_date` is set in `$fillable`

Comment: If you are sure that the due_date field is in that $fillable property, then manually check the database and make sure you can change that column to nullable